# Missing tag in an XML prevents a XmlSerializer to create a property

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a problem when using the XmlSerializer class for deserializing an xml stream.

I have an object like that :

```
public class Test
{
  [XmlElement("data")]
  public AnotherObject Data
  {
    get; set;
  }

  // other properties
}
```

It will work properly when I will try to deserialize that :

```
<Test>
  <data>...</data>
  <something else... />
</Test>
```

However, if the xml is like :

```
<Test>
  <something else... />   
</Test>
```

When I will try to read the Data property of the newly created object, the code will throw an exception. If I try to observe the object, the debugger prints a "Could not evaluate exception".

I want the property to exist, even if there is no corresponding tag in the XML.

Is it possible to do that ?

Thanks !

Comment: Do you just mean `.Data` is a `null` reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML deserialization uses the calls the default constructor before setting the properties. You could set the `data` property to a default value there that will be overwritten if one is loaded from the deserialization.

Comment: It was simple as that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps:

```
public class Test
{
  [XmlElement("data")]
  public System.Nullable<AnotherObject> Data
  {
    get; set;
  }

  // other properties
}
```

That will allow a null value to be accepted for AnotherObject, essentially allowing Data to be null.

NOTE: This is very dependant upon your schema. If your schema prevents null values, this will not work. For more information see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx